# what are the omitted values in the code, _____ represents omitted values

Tags: python

I have a code and i want to know what will make the code work... ____ represents the missing values of the code

````
def dice(num_of_rolls, seed):
    rolled_list = []
    random.___(seed)

    for i in range(0,num_of_rolls+1):
        rolled_list.append(____.randint(1,6))
        dict_of_rolls = ____i : rolled_list[i] for i in range(1, len(rolled_list) )____
        
    return dict_of_rolls
```

can anyone help?
````

Comment: This looks like your homework.  The purpose of this exercise is to teach you how to read documentation.  You won't learn anything from asking for help on the web.

Comment: that's true...thanks, i just figured it out